# Forms.context is obsolete.Context is obsolete as of version 2.5,please use a local context instead

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I run into this problem:
Forms.context is obsolete.Context is obsolete as of version 2.5,please use a local context instead.

I m trying to login using Azure Active Directory with code below. 
Please help.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using myMobile.Service;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(myMobile.Droid.Authenticator))]
namespace myMobile.Droid
{
    class Authenticator: IAuthenticator 
    {
        public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string tenantUrl, string graphResourceUri, string ApplicationID, string returnUri)
        {
            try
            {
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(tenantUrl);
                if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
                    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().FirstOrDefault().Authority);

  var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceUri, ApplicationID, new Uri(returnUri), new PlatformParameters((Activity)Forms.Context));

                return authResult;
            }
            catch (Exception)       
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}


// err encountered on this line :(Activity)Forms.Context)

 Forms.context is obsolete.Context is obsolete as of version2.5,please use a local context instead.

var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceUri, ApplicationID, new Uri(returnUri), new PlatformParameters((Activity)Forms.Context));
```

//--- Update :

```
 //-------- Login Page:

private async void Login()
{           
     try
     {
       var data = await DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>()
                  .Authenticate(AzureSettings.tenanturl, AzureSettings.GraphResourceUri, AzureSettings.ApplicationID, AzureSettings.ReturnUri);

  AzureSettings.AuthenticationResult = data;

                //NavigateTopage(data);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
        }
   }

//--------- in Shared Project :

//-- interface: IAuthenticator


using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myMobile.Service
{
    public interface IAuthenticator
    {
        Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string tenantUrl, string graphResourceUri, string ApplicationID, string returnUri);
    }
}



//-------- in Android Project: add

1) Class : Authenticator.cs

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using myMobile.Service;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(myMobile.Droid.Authenticator))]
namespace myMobile.Droid
{
    class Authenticator: IAuthenticator 
    {
        private readonly Context _context;

        public static void Init(Context context)
        {
            _context = context;  //--error 
        }


        public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string tenantUrl, string graphResourceUri, string ApplicationID, string returnUri)
        {
            try
            {
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(tenantUrl);
                if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
                    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().FirstOrDefault().Authority);

var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceUri, ApplicationID, new Uri(returnUri), new PlatformParameters((Activity) _context));

                return authResult;
            }
            catch (Exception)       
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

error : 

An Object reference is required for non-static field,method or property.Authenticator._context



//------- Class: MainActivity



namespace myMobile.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "myMobile", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

               DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>().Init(this);  //<-- Error

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}

Error Message:

IUAthenticator does not contain a definition for Init and no extension method accepting
a first argument of  type IAuthenticator
```

Answer (score 2):

You now have to implement a custom constructor that takes a `Context` put that in a local variable and use that instead of this for instance `new PlatformParameters((Activity)Forms.Context)`.

For a custom renderer, you can use the solution underneath. Do like this:

```
public MyControlRenderer : ControlRenderer
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    public MyControlRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

For a dependency service like yours, you will have to find a way to supply the `Context`. Since Xamarin.Forms uses a single activity, you can get away with some kind of init method.

Add this to your code:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private static Context _context;

    public static void Init(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Now call the `Init` from your `MainActivity` and you should be good after that. So do: `DependencyService.Get<IMyService>().Init(this);`

For other people coming across this for multiple activities, please refer to the documentation here: https://www.davidbritch.com/2017/11/xamarinforms-25-and-local-context-on.html that is what this is inspired on.

Comment: with base(context), this will show error. Use this base(), there is no error. Which one to use? err: object does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: My bad, thought it was a custom renderer, see the updated answer

Comment: I have updated the entire code base on your approach. I got error in Authenticator.cs class and MainActivity Class.  Am I doing it right?

Comment: If you're getting errors, then probably not. I don't see the changes updated in your answer?

Comment: In the update section: I list out 1) LoginPage 2) the Interface: IAuthenticator 3) Classes in Android Project; in a) Authenticator class, I used your Injection approach , in  b) MainActivity, I added the Method to call Init. Both a) & b) has error which I list out.  I think I may not doing it right. Can you correct my mistake if I did not follow your approach correctly. Thanks